# What is the reference of this saying/quote?

Tags: hadith, reference-request

What is the reference of quote/saying in attached photo?? is it a hadith of Prophet Muhammad(Peace be Upon Him)

[image]??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an authentic meaning conveyed by the Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ).

It's derived from Musnad Ahmad.

The Ahmad hadith (exact wording) of the Prophet can be read below:

> إنك لن تدع شيئاً لله عز وجل إلا بدلك الله به ما هو خير لك منه
>
> English: [Allah will replace it with something better](https://abuaminaelias.com/dailyhadithonline/2014/01/13/allah-replace-something-better/)

You can read the discussion of the statement in your quote at the following link:

Arabic:  [من ترك شيئا لله عوضه الله خيرا منه](https://islamqa.info/ar/answers/252813/%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%B1%D9%83-%D8%B4%D9%8A%D9%89%D8%A7-%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%B6%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%84%D9%87-%D8%AE%D9%8A%D8%B1%D8%A7-%D9%85%D9%86%D9%87)

**Answer slightly modified.

Comment: For any who was not able to find on sunnah.com it's because Musnad ahmed is considered to be among the nine books of hadith of the Sunnah of the Prophet (ﷺ). It consists of 28199 ahadith organized by 1277 narrators.
And only 4% of it is available on https://sunnah.com/ahmad yet. It will be completed soon insha allah.